# Basic Auth allowing users to pass through without credentails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I have written a Spring Security Class. But somehow it is not working as expected. I am trying to hit the Rest APIs via a Postman by selecting the Basic Auth method. And here is the scenario.

1. Correct username and password --> Works (I get 200 responses)
2. Incorrect username/password --> Works (I get 401 responses)
3. Select No Auth in Postman --> Doesn't Work (I should get 401, but it allows the request to pass through)

Now for #1 and #2 it works fine. Its the #3 that is the troublesome part. My Security code is written like:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("\${spring.security.user.name}")
    private val userName : String? = null

    @Value("\${spring.user.password}")
    private val password : String? = null

    @Autowired
    lateinit var appAuthenticationEntryPoint: AppAuthenticationEntryPoint


    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return MyPasswordDelegation().createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()
    }


    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun userDetailsService(): InMemoryUserDetailsManager? {

        val userDetails : UserDetails = User.withUsername(userName).password(passwordEncoder().encode(password)).roles("USER").build()

        return InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails)
    }


    @Throws(Exception::class)
    @Bean
    fun filterChain(httpSecurity : HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()

        // Allow only HTTPS Requests
        httpSecurity.requiresChannel {
                channel -> channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure()
        }.authorizeRequests {
                authorize -> authorize.antMatchers("/app-download/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
         .httpBasic()
             .and()
         .exceptionHandling()
         .authenticationEntryPoint(myAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        }

        return httpSecurity.build()
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What URL do you call?

Comment: @dur The URL that I try to call is `https://localhost:8443/app-download/deviceConfig`